# How to use outputLinks to display and navigate dates

Tags: outputlink

I have two outputlinks to show previous/next Date on a page. But it appears like whichever one gets declared first takes priority and the other one does not render. i.e. it doesn't change the dates.

In my visualforce, I have the following:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, date, dd-MM'-'yyyy}" id="dateId">
    <apex:param value="{!viewDate}"/>
</apex:outputText>
<apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.APP_CalendarApp}?date={!nextDate}"> next </apex:outputLink>
<apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.APP_CalendarApp}?date={!prevDate}"> previous </apex:outputLink>
```

the constructor:

```
public APP_CalendarAppCTRL() {
    gatherRecords();

    recordStr = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('recordStr') == Null ? 'Photographer' : ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('recordStr');
    viewDate = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('date') == Null ? Date.today() : Date.parse(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('date'));
}
```

and these sets the dates:

```
public Date getprevDate() {
    viewDate = viewDate.addDays(-1);
    String formatted = viewDate.year() + '-' + viewDate.month() + '-' + viewDate.day();
    Date newDate = Date.ValueOf(formatted);
    return newDate;
}

public Date getnextDate() {
    viewDate = viewDate.addDays(+1);
    String formatted = viewDate.year() + '-' + viewDate.month() + '-' + viewDate.day();
    Date newDate = Date.ValueOf(formatted);
    return newDate;
}
```

The view dates does not change on the page if clicked on previous. Any help? please let me know if more details needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both getters modify your `viewDate` property, whereas neither should. Your getters should be idempotent.

Instead of:

```
viewDate = viewDate.addDays(1);
```

Use:

```
Date nextDate = viewDate.addDays(1);
```

And make sure you substitute this pointer variable in for `viewDate`.